# Tkinter -- how is root connected to the Frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, canvas, window

I am learning to use the Python library *tkinter* and I found this code snippet that creates a simple window with an orange rectangle.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        canvas = Canvas(self)
        canvas.create_rectangle(30, 10, 120, 80, outline="#fb0", fill="#fb0")
        canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    ex = Example()
    root.geometry("200x100")
    root.mainloop()
```

in the main function, could anyone explaine how the object `ex` is plugged in with the object `root`? I do not understand how these two objects are related.

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe tkinter is assuming that since you didn't give the frame a `master` argument,  you want to pack the frame into the newest or current instance of `Tk`? There's no visible relationship, so I don't know what else it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Every widget must have a parent/master except for the root window. If you don't specify one, a default will be used. The default is the root window. If there is no root window, one will be created automatically.

In your case you don't pass anything to `Example()` so by default its parent is the root window. As a rule of thumb you should always explicitly specify the parent when creating a widget.